# CSS Question-- Selecting Div Class Based on Its Child

Tags: css, css-selectors

Sorry for a basic question. But, I need some help.

In CSS, how can I select a div class only when it has a specific child? So, for example:

```
<div class="specialClass">
   <div id="myDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Let's say I only want to change specialClass' background to red, if it has a child called myDiv.

```
what_selector? {
      background-color: #FF0000;
    }
```

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't! Selectors go **down** the document tree.

Also without demerit to @Jeroen, don't use w3schools as a reference. It is known to provide wrong and outdated information.

Check out [Sitepoint's CSS Reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css) for accurate and updated CSS intel.

Maybe if you further explain your goal, we can suggest a solution.

Comment: Hi @Pedro Correia, Thank you for the help. I found a workaround, so I'm all set. Also, thanks for the Sitepoint link. In the past I used w3schools as a reference.